# How can I move a div from top to bottom by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make an effect like : click a button, and the top div will hide, then bottom div will scroll from top to bottom.

I have finished hide the top div, but it's failed to make the bottom div getting down (?

I think maybe it's because my css and js get something wrong (?), but I'm not sure, and I've modified several times. = (

Here's my javascript code:

```
$(function(){

        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $(".slot-top").hide();
            $("#slot ul").animate({ top: "0em" },1500);
            return false;
        });

    });
```

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/b1mj1c1L/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up the jQuery Selector. 
Instead of `$("#slot ul").animate({ top: "0em" },1500);` use `$(".slot").animate({ top: "0em" },1500);`.
See here: https://jsfiddle.net/b1mj1c1L/1/

Comment: Thanks!! I 'm really in a mess. Thank you very much!!